# Handlerbar refresh list instead of append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, handlebars.js

This is the code I am using to append data -

```
schoolNews = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data.data.posts));
$(".schoolNewsList").append (theTemplate(schoolNews)); 
$("#scroller ul").listview().listview('refresh');
```

Now what I want to do is refresh the whole list instead of appending data to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if you are using a control for the `listview()` functionality. I am not certain what that is and do not know how to interface with that. However, in looking at your code, I am seeing that you are calling the `append()` function, instead of the `html()`. Calling `html()` will replace all code inside of the element.

### New Code:

```
schoolNews = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data.data.posts));
$(".schoolNewsList").html (theTemplate(schoolNews));
// instead of appending the values, set the value of the html
$("#scroller ul").listview().listview('refresh');
```

Comment: I have to wait 11 more minutes to vote this as the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do:

```
schoolNews = data.data.posts;  //No need for encoding decoding
$(".schoolNewsList").html(theTemplate(schoolNews));   //Replace contents instead of appending
$("#scroller ul").listview().listview('refresh');
```

Cheers